# How to parallel download multiple files with NodeJS and execute callback when finished?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a list of media files (mp3, wav, mp4, png, ...) which looks like the sample below, but can be quite longer:

```
{
    "0000": {
        "type": "audio",
        "path": "animals_sequence.mp3"
    },
    "0010": {
        "type": "video",
        "path": "success.mp4"
    }
}
```

Once downloaded from the server, my script is meant to parse this list, then download all the files specified in it from the server, in case they don't exist locally. And what I'm trying to achieve is a parallel download of these files and to execute a callback once they're all downloaded. The farthest I've come is the code below, which at some point, breaks with the following error and leaves a lot of empty files on disk. :)

```
 MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added to [WriteStream]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

And here's the code I have, which doesn't work:

```
        let pathToMediaFile;
        let remoteFileURL;
        let fileExistsLocally = false;
        let file, request;

        media = require('../media.json');

        for (const code in media) {
            if ( !('type' in media[code]) || !('path' in media[code])) {
                continue;
            }

            pathToMediaFile = `/home/pi/application/media/${media[code]['type']}/${media[code]['path']}`;

            try {
                fs.accessSync(pathToMediaFile, fs.constants.R_OK);
                fileExistsLocally = true;
            } catch (err) {
                fileExistsLocally = false;
            }

            if (fileExistsLocally) {
                console.log('File', pathToMediaFile, 'exists locally');
                continue;
            }

            remoteFileURL = `${serverAddress}/media/${media[code]['type']}/${media[code]['path']}`;
            console.log('Attempting to download missing file from', remoteFileURL);

            file = fs.createWriteStream(pathToMediaFile);
            request = http.get(remoteFileURL, (response) => {
                console.log(remoteFileURL, 'download status:', response.statusCode);
                if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
                    return;
                }

                response.pipe(file);
                file.on('finish', function () {
                    file.close(function (){
                        console.log('Finished downloading', remoteFileURL);
                    }) ;
                }).on('error', function (err) {
                    console.log('Error downloading', remoteFileURL, ':', err);
                    fs.unlink(pathToMediaFile, function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log('Could not unlink', pathToMediaFile);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        }
```

Comment: Maybe you need `file`, `request` and other ones be not global, but local for each iteration, otherwise it could mess up all async code. Try to declare all variables except `media` inside `for` loop.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, they're not global. However, I've created an array of files instead of reusing that single one, but it still doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to remain you main workflow, just made some variables more local and adjusted some small things according to my taste, and it seems OK. Tested on the last Node.js release files:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');

const media = {
  "0001": { type: "file", path: "SHASUMS256.txt" },
  "0002": { type: "file", path: "SHASUMS256.txt.asc" },
  "0003": { type: "file", path: "SHASUMS256.txt.sig" },
  "0004": { type: "file", path: "node-v16.6.0-aix-ppc64.tar.gz" },
  "0005": { type: "file", path: "node-v16.6.0-darwin-arm64.tar.gz" },
  "0006": { type: "file", path: "node-v16.6.0-darwin-arm64.tar.xz" },
  "0007": { type: "file", path: "node-v16.6.0-darwin-x64.tar.gz" },
  "0008": { type: "file", path: "node-v16.6.0-darwin-x64.tar.xz" },
  "0009": { type: "file", path: "node-v16.6.0-headers.tar.gz" },
  "0010": { type: "file", path: "node-v16.6.0-headers.tar.xz" },
  "0011": { type: "file", path: "node-v16.6.0-linux-arm64.tar.gz" },
  "0012": { type: "file", path: "node-v16.6.0-linux-arm64.tar.xz" },
  "0013": { type: "file", path: "node-v16.6.0-linux-armv7l.tar.gz" },
  "0014": { type: "file", path: "node-v16.6.0-linux-armv7l.tar.xz" },
  "0015": { type: "file", path: "node-v16.6.0-linux-ppc64le.tar.gz" },
  "0016": { type: "file", path: "node-v16.6.0-linux-ppc64le.tar.xz" },
  "0017": { type: "file", path: "node-v16.6.0-linux-s390x.tar.gz" },
  "0018": { type: "file", path: "node-v16.6.0-linux-s390x.tar.xz" },
  "0019": { type: "file", path: "node-v16.6.0-linux-x64.tar.gz" },
  "0020": { type: "file", path: "node-v16.6.0-linux-x64.tar.xz" },
  "0021": { type: "file", path: "node-v16.6.0-win-x64.7z" },
  "0022": { type: "file", path: "node-v16.6.0-win-x64.zip" },
  "0023": { type: "file", path: "node-v16.6.0-win-x86.7z" },
  "0024": { type: "file", path: "node-v16.6.0-win-x86.zip" },
  "0025": { type: "file", path: "node-v16.6.0-x64.msi" },
  "0026": { type: "file", path: "node-v16.6.0-x86.msi" },
  "0027": { type: "file", path: "node-v16.6.0.pkg" },
  "0028": { type: "file", path: "node-v16.6.0.tar.gz" },
  "0029": { type: "file", path: "node-v16.6.0.tar.xz" },
};

const serverAddress = 'https://nodejs.org/download/release/latest';

for (const fileItem of Object.values(media)) {
    if (!('type' in fileItem) || !('path' in fileItem)) {
        continue;
    }

    const pathToMediaFile = `./${fileItem.type}/${fileItem.path}`;

    if (fs.existsSync(pathToMediaFile)) {
        console.log('File', pathToMediaFile, 'exists locally');
        continue;
    }

    const remoteFileURL = `${serverAddress}/${fileItem.path}`;
    console.log('Attempting to download missing file from', remoteFileURL);

    const file = fs.createWriteStream(pathToMediaFile);
    https.get(remoteFileURL, (response) => {
        console.log(remoteFileURL, 'download status:', response.statusCode);
        if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
            return;
        }

        response.pipe(file);
        file.on('finish', function () {
            file.close(function () {
                console.log('Finished downloading', remoteFileURL);
            });
        }).on('error', function (err) {
            console.log('Error downloading', remoteFileURL, ':', err);
            fs.unlink(pathToMediaFile, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Could not unlink', pathToMediaFile);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```